# Two materials on one object

Tags: materials

I'm trying to do something simple and I know there are a few tutorials on how to do this but the steps set out don't seem to work for me.  What i want to achieve is a tile with an asphalt image texture on one side and a grass texture on the other.

The video shows the problem i'm having https://vimeo.com/239592554 although the resolution is not that great.

My workflow is:

1. select object and enter edit mode
2. select required face
3. type 'U' and unwrap face
4. create new material
5. select 'image texture'
6. find asphalt image and select
7. assign material
8. turn the object over and select opposite face
9. repeat steps 2 to 7 using the image of grass

The problem i have is that the grass then appears on both faces.  I can't see what i'm doing wrong but hopefully you can.  I'm using Cycles.

Many thanks in advance.

Stephen

Following helpful responses, I've tried with a fresh instance of Blender and a 'straight out of the box' mesh cube.  Then tried to add basic BSDF materials to separate faces but every time the material gets applied to the whole cube not just the selected face.

Could it be something to do with my Blender set up/user preferences?  I can't think what.  Anyway, gif of the new test included below:

[image]

Comment: i think u trying on the normal plane not on the cube with low height as shown in the video

Comment: Hi Atek and thank you for coming back to me. Not sure i understand your comment though, could you elaborate for me?  Appreciate your help.

Comment: can u plz show me screenshot what material or texture and how ur using it on what mesh

Comment: Hi Atek, see my gif and comments above.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood with the gif file you have send. 2 Material on single cube

Click on the material and it will add the material to complete cube. Name it as 1

Add new material with the + sign in the material. Name it as 2

[image]

Go to edit mode and select the face you want to add the new material or material 2 and click on assign.

[image]

And change the view port color also same red and green below or u can drag the color on the view port color.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Atek, but how do i drop .jpg images into the viewport colour box?  So far the only way i can make it work is to use two planes, allocate a separate material/texture to each and then make them part of a single object in 'object' mode, then joining vertices to make new faces.  Very cumbersome and leaves the edges with strange colouring.

Comment: No the viewport is for color not for image. I have show the material u can add material also same way. Just to assume u can fix the viewport color for example green for grass

Comment: Stephen, at the right of the color, you press the "point" button, and you can select "image texture" instead of a pure colour. Or, if ou wish, after following Atek's tut, you change to node view, and work from there, inserting your images.

Comment: Thanks MCunha, I am familiar with both the selection of image textures and the use of material nodes.  My problem is, none of it seems to work!!  I've even tried opening a new instance of Blender and working on an unedited cube but it will not accept material textures (.jpg images) on anything other than all faces.  I'm completely baffled but appreciate the help/ideas you guys are coming up with.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a "double side material" node setup with the geometry node (selecting the backfacing option). The following image presents half a cube where the exterior is grass and the interior is gravel. The backfacing option uses the same UVmap but shows the texture for the other side of the faces, so from your steps, you can ignore step 8 and step 9. The same technique is used to create double sided pages, in a book or similar.
[image]

Comment: you can even try using different UVmaps, if you don't plan to use the other side of the faces, but put different textures on different faces. Consider the following tutorial on managing different UVmaps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqmXqgbzIxg

Comment: Thanks MCunha for coming back so promptly but sadly none of this works for me.  I've tried everything from recreating the tile to deleting all materials, textures, UV maps and starting all over again, but I still get the same image on both sides.  Your node map was helpful as was the tutorial but I can't see what is causing the problem.

Comment: LIke most people, UV maps are a bit of mystery to me, especially as the names at the bottom of the image editor don't seem to be synced with those in the mesh properties panel - they both get assigned independently, and neither seems to have anything to do with materials when they are assigned.  It just seems to be a whole bunch of separate data that doesn't interact in any way.  Am baffled but appreciative!!

Comment: MCunha - I've realised the node tree you put together applies materials/textures to opposite sides of a plane, not a solid object.  Useful to know but it doesn't create the tile object i'm looking for.  Appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Atek and MCunha for their efforts in trying to sort out my problem, it is very much appreciated.

I solved the problem eventually after much searching and hair tearing - because my tile was a modified version of a previous shape, there was some duplicate geometry in there that was invisible. 'Remove doubles' eventually tidied it up and the materials worked as required.  A great relief.  Will now get on with what i was trying to do in the first place!!