# Blender - apply image texture to specific parts of the object

Tags: texturing, uv

I've been trying for so long to apply an image texture to a specific part of an object in Blender for a while and I really need an opinion of an expert here.

So, my object looks like below (front, side and back):

[image: Front]

[image: Side]

[image: Back]

What I want is to apply an image texture only to these specific parts of the object. I've tried so far:

- to do it by using nodes (Material properties) - didn't worked as it apply the image texture to the whole object;
- importing the texture paint, select the specific parts (using "Texture Paint" as object interaction mode), selected as "Mask Mapping" the option "Stencil" and applied - it worked somehow, however the image texture applied it's not the same on both faces (has different axes positions). Also, the above part of the object (the middle part between front and back) it stays always black.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?  You have tagged your question with [tag:blender-internal-render-engine], however this tag indicates a specific render engine which is no longer present in the latest versions of Blender so I suspect you may not actually be understanding this tag correctly.  This is important as applying textures differs based on the render engine being used.

Comment: @PGmath - I'm using 2.92.0. About the tags, I wasn't able to find/identify one that was suggestive to my question.

Comment: You're probably using Eevee or Cycles.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is that first you make two material slots. Give one slot any other texture you want and the other slot the image texture you want to apply to a specific part of mesh. Then go to edit mode, select the parts of your mesh you wan't your material to appear on and then press apply after selcting the right material.

Here are some tutuorials from youtube for beginners: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ms89wP8m4ZU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXpbK2T1HJA

Comment: You lost me as I'm new to Blender. Could you provide any tutorial for it or post here an example? Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/93024/107598 for pictures. Here an old video with Suzanne (the monkey): https://youtu.be/sXPscduUxbM but it still works the same. The render engine *Cycles* is on the right side where all the vertical icons (tabs) are. Choose the 2nd. There you can switch between *Eevee* and *Cycles*